# Is there any benefit to returning a value from function as opposed to returning void?

Tags: oop, function, coldfusion, return, return-value

I work primarily in ColdFusion, a non-compiled language, but this is a general question for all languages.

I'm creating objects with getters/setters as well as CRUD methods. Here's a sample:

```
<cffunction name="getPeriodStartDate" output="false" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.PeriodStartDate />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setPeriodStartDate" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <cfargument name="PeriodStartDate" type="Numeric" required="true" />

    <cfset VARIABLES.PeriodStartDate = ARGUMENTS.PeriodStartDate />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getDollarAmount" output="false" returntype="Numeric">
    <cfreturn VARIABLES.DollarAmount />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="setDollarAmount" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <cfargument name="DollarAmount" type="Numeric" required="true" />

    <cfset VARIABLES.DollarAmount = ARGUMENTS.DollarAmount />
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="read" output="false" returntype="Query">
    <!---
    READ QUERY
    --->

    <cfreturn _qData />
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="create" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <!---
    INSERT QUERY
    --->
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="update" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <!---
    UPDATE QUERY
    --->
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="delete" output="false" returntype="Void">
    <!---
    DELETE QUERY
    --->
</cffunction>
```

Obviously the `get` methods and the `read()` methods will return a value.

But, is there any benefit to have the other methods return a value - perhaps a Boolean?

I've worked in Flex/ActionScript and remember that in most cases, I needed to return some value from a method and set a variable to that result in order to prevent the next line of code from processing:

```
function myFunc() {
    x = getSomething();

    y = getSomethingElse(x);
}
```

Comment: Will you inspect that value and do anything? It is that data going to be used for anything? If no, then there is no reason to return a value for kicks.

Answer (score 5):

If you return `this` on your setters, you can chain the setters.  I think CF10 accessors return `this`to enable chaining by default.

I read that returning `void` would be more efficient a while back, but I'm not sure if it is true anymore.  I doubt the difference would be noticeable.